# Darle movimiento indefinido a varias figuras en canvas tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas

estoy haciendo un programa en canvas donde necesito darle movimiento indefinido a  varias figuras rectangulares(10)  al mismo tiempo, si bien puedo darle movimiento a cada figura por separado, eso seria escribir muchas líneas de código.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de darle movimiento sin tener que repetir la función por cada figura.

este es el codigo que e creado hasta el momento:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Ventana:
    def __init__(self):
        self.principal=tk.Tk()                
        self.canvas1=tk.Canvas(self.principal,width=400,height=300)
        self.canvas1.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.figura=self.canvas1.create_rectangle(10,10,30,30,fill="black")        
        self.movimiento()        
        self.principal.mainloop()
   
        
    def movimiento(self):
        self.canvas1.move(self.figura,0,3)
        if self.canvas1.coords(self.figura)[2]>300:
            self.canvas1.move(self.figura,-350,0)
        elif self.canvas1.coords(self.figura)[2]<0:
            self.canvas1.move(self.figura,300,0)
        elif self.canvas1.coords(self.figura)[3]>350:
            self.canvas1.move(self.figura,0,-350)
        elif self.canvas1.coords(self.figura)[3]<0:
            self.canvas1.move(self.figura,0,300)
        self.principal.after(100,self.movimiento)  

        
inicio=Ventana()
```

de ante mano le doy gracias por la ayuda brindada

Answer (score 0):

El mejor truco que uso es crear una clase. En esa clase guardamos el id de la figura.
También agregaremos el método update, que se encargará de actualizar la posición de la figura. Aceptará de argumento el canvas donde está la figura.

Cuando tengamos que crear una figura, la guardamos en una lista.

Cuando necesitemos actualizar la posición de cada figura, recorremos la lista de las figuras y, por cada figura, llamamos al método update.

A continuación, agrego una demo:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class Figure:
    def __init__(self, iid):
        self.id = iid

    def update(self, canvas):
        canvas.move(self.id,0,3)
        
        if canvas.coords(self.id)[2]>300:
            canvas.move(self.id,-350,0)
        elif canvas.coords(self.id)[2]<0:
            canvas.move(self.id,300,0)
        elif canvas.coords(self.id)[3]>350:
            canvas.move(self.id,0,-350)
        elif canvas.coords(self.id)[3]<0:
            canvas.move(self.id,0,300)
    

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400,height=300)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.figures = []

        width = 40
        height= 40

        for _ in range(4):
            x = random.randrange(400 - width)
            y = random.randrange(300 - height)
            
            self.figures.append(Figure(self.canvas.create_rectangle(x,y,x + width,y + height,fill="black")))

        self.movimiento()
        
    def movimiento(self):
        for figure in self.figures:
            figure.update(self.canvas)

        self.after(100,self.movimiento)
            
        
root = Window()
root.mainloop()
```